# genus of connected sum G(Q1#Q2)

Tags: surfaces

could you tell me a a mathematical publication where i can find the proof of why the genus of connected sum G(Q1#Q2) is G(Q1) + G(Q2)  for orientable surface and 2G(Q1) + G(Q2) otherwise.
I need it to make a bibliographic set of a thesis.

Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion: add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

Comment: Thank you! @DietrichBurde